# Import mxnet error in python windows10

Tags: windows, python-2.7, mxnet

I installed mxnet in python in windows.

```
>>> import mxnet
```

There is a mistake.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "d:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mxnet-0.7.0-    py2.7.egg\mxnet\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .base import MXNetError
     File "d:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mxnet-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\mxnet\base.py", line 43, in <module>
      _LIB = _load_lib()
     File "d:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mxnet-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\mxnet\base.py", line 35, in _load_lib
     lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
     File "d:\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
     File "d:\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    WindowsError: [Error 126]`

I  have reinstalled mxnet and anaconda2 many times but it is still wrong.I made mxnet install successfully once 5 months ago.
I used Dependency Walker to see what lost,but there are too many to find files.I don't know where to find these DLL files.[image]

I want to know which step i do wrong.

Comment: Try searching `mxnet windows error 126` in google and you'll be amazed on what will pop up

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what' happend to you. But I did install mxnet successfully in win10 and python2.7. If you can read Chinese, you can read my blog:https://my.oschina.net/qinhui99/blog/845249.

Answer (score 0):

Register and download cuDNN at Nvidai site and overwrite include and lib file in the relavant pathof your CUDA installed lication.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it got solved by using anaconda prompt:

> > > python
> > >
> > > import mxnet